# How can I legally access and modify the private fields vector and map without violating encapsulation?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, data-structures, stl

I am trying to implement the Depth First Search as a function which takes in a Graph and outputs the DFS.

```
class Graph
{
private:
  int V;
  int timestamp;
  std:: vector<std:: list<int> > graph;
  std:: map<int, vertex> nodemap;
public:
  Graph(int V);
  int Size();

  void addEdge(int u, int v);
  void printEdges();
  void printVertices();
};
```

Above is the class I have made for the Graph. I am trying to make a function that returns the pointer to both the **private vector and map** so that I can perform **for loop** operations on the Adjacency List and the Map data structures of the Graph. However, I know that manipulating the data structures directly is a violation of encapsulation and I wanted to maintain the Object Oriented discipline of my program. How is this possible to do so without violation of encapsulation?

**PS:** I am not looking forward to using friend function as I do not want to make the function an exception. I want to find a mainstream solution which is popularly exercised by programmers and is a disciplined solution. I can change my Class fields/accessibility if needed though.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you have a `public` function that returns a copy of the `map` and `vector`? Assuming the callers don't need to modify elements, there shouldn't be an issue doing so.

Comment: You can return (const) iterators to the `begin()` and `end()` of each sequence, which will allow iterating but not insertion or deletion.  Unfortunately that doesn't provide lookup for the `std::map`.

Comment: The callers do need to modify elements.

Comment: @BenVoigt Insertion and deletion is needed. :(

Comment: What's the purpose of your `addEdge(u,v)` member function then?  Won't direct modification of these containers allow the caller to break your invariants?

Comment: Okay seems like I'll have to give up on the plan of modifying the vectors and maps, how can I return a copy of map and vector? :)

Comment: Add_Edge is a function that adds an edge from node u to node v, and it is not breaking encapsulation as it is modifying the private variables via a public function?

Comment: Do you mean to make it a member function?

Comment: Okay, to be honest, I also tried to break the encapsulation but I couldn't get to go about it. How can I make a function that returns the pointer to these vectors and maps, so that I can also modify, add, insert, remove elements to the vector and the map?

Comment: Yes, it is a public function @Galik ?

Comment: You would be a lot better off maintaining encapsulation and adding get, set, insert, and delete methods to do the work for you. That way `Graph` can add in checks to trap and disallow harmful/insane manipulations. Think of getters and setters as self defense for objects. Hand over a `vector` of `list`s and some inattentive code could remove a whole `list` by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to iterator over the adjacency map, then you add a member function that allows you to do so.

You have two obvious options:

1. Define your own AdjacencyMapIterator class and provide `begin()` / `end()` that return instances of those.
2. Provide a function taking a functor, with the functor getting called on each entry in the adjacency map.

The first would look like this:

```
for(auto it = graph.adjacency_begin() ; it!=graph.adjacency_end(); ++it) {
   vertex& v1 = it->v1;
   vertex& v2 = it->v2;
   ...
}
```

The second would look like

```
graph.for_each_adjacency(
   [](vertex& v1, vertex &v2) { .... }
);
```

The biggest problem is working out how to handle changes to your graph structure during iteration. Most implementations I've seen either explicitly disallow this (either by throwing an exception, or stating that doing so is undefined behaviour), or operate the iteration on an internal copy. If you need something different - expect it to be a pain point in future.

if you want to do some updates in a loop where updating inside the loop is not allowed, just loop storing the requires updates somewhere, then apply all the updates after the loop is completed:

```
std::vector<UpdateInfo> updates;
graph.for_each_adjacency( [&updates](const vertex& v1, const vertex& v2) { 
   updates.push_back( calculateUpdate(v1,v2) );
} );

foreach(updates, [&graph](const UdpateInfo &update) {
   applyUpdate(update, graph); 
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decide if you're "object oriented" or not.  If not, then you've just got a structure (aka record) so make your fields public and party on.  But if you're O-O then there's a couple of ways to go.  You could provide accessors on `Graph` that, e.g., one which given a vertex returns edges (or adjacent vertices).  Then you write your traversal algorithm external to the Graph.  Alternatively, you provide your traversal algorithm as a method of `Graph` and it has direct access to the private members.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was doing (you provide your traversal algorithm as a method of Graph and it has direct access to the private members) however I had a tingy feeling that it was not right. Just asking is there anything legally wrong with it? Is it violating OOP in anyway?

Comment: @DanishAmjadAlvi  No, it is definitely O-O.  Very very often you'll find algorithms right inside the class, especially where they need to be tightly coupled.  In some cases though there are benefits to keeping them separate.  E.g., suppose you wanted to code several algorithms - traversals, maximal connections, etc.  _Then_ suppose you wanted different _representations_ - e.g., you currently have adjacency list, but you might want to use - for various reasons, in other cases - adjacency matrix, incidence matrix, or something else.  You might prefer then  to have your algorithms separate.